# Как узнать, входит ли данный индекс в словарь C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("1", "text1");
dict.Add("2", "text2");
bool exists = dict.Exists("3"); (как?)
```

Comment: В словаре есть ключи и значения. Индексов в словаре нет.

Comment: Да, точно. А как узнать, входит ли ключ в коллекцию (любую)?

Comment: Ключи есть только в словарях. В условной коллекции есть просто элементы. Чтобы понять, присутствует элемент в коллеции или нет, есть метод `mycollection.Contains(myItem)`. Важно понимать, что результат метода зависит от того, как элементы реализуют методы Equals и GetHashCode

Comment: В ICollection нет метода Contains.

Comment: [`ICollection<T>.Contains(T) Method`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8)